# Strange selection pushdown in postgres 13

Tags: postgresql

Trying to sample (not uniformly) a flight delay table in postgres I stumbled on a weird pushdown of selection with a subquery.

```
with
     grp_counts as (select month , 0.01 c from  flights group by  month)
select grp_counts.c, month, "arrival_delay", "weather_delay", "airline_delay", "security_delay", "diverted", "cancelled" from flights natural join grp_counts
where random() < grp_counts.c;
```

I'm expecting to get about 1% of the table this way but instead I get 0 tuples most of the time the reason is postgres decided to move the selection into the subquery as per the plan:

```
Hash Join  (cost=176109.82..358341.36 rows=1939641 width=60)
  Hash Cond: (flights.month = grp_counts.month)
  ->  Seq Scan on flights  (cost=0.00..161562.24 rows=5818924 width=28)
  ->  Hash  (cost=176109.77..176109.77 rows=4 width=36)
        ->  Subquery Scan on grp_counts  (cost=176109.55..176109.77 rows=4 width=36)
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=176109.55..176109.73 rows=4 width=36)
                    Group Key: flights_1.month
                    Filter: (random() < '0.01'::double precision)
                    ->  Seq Scan on flights flights_1  (cost=0.00..161562.24 rows=5818924 width=4)
```

I'm really surprised by this and not quite sure if it's a bug or I'm not up to speed on the with clause ....

Comment: What version are you using? Have your tried messing around with `AS MATERIALIZED`?

Comment: I can reproduce this and I don't see how this can be anything but a bug.  Please report it to the bugs mailing list.

Comment: @Vérace I'm using 13.4, `AS MATERIALIZED` doesn't do it still pushed down the selection before the join. @jjanes thanks for the sanity check I'll try and send a clean bug report this week

Answer (score 0):

The inner sequential scan on `flights` is unavoidable because of your strange `WHERE` condition.

The outer sequential scan might be avoided with an index on `month`.

Since the query makes no sense to me, I cannot suggest improvements on it.