# Reuse Randomly Generated String Across Multiple Columns

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to create a SELECT statement that would become a VIEW to pull data and mask certain columns. The idea being a hostname is reused in a few columns. I want to generate a random string, which I can do, but use that randomly generated value across 3 columns. 1 is just the string, another is another column and the generated value concatenated and a third is another string concatenated with it.

```
SELECT log.logentity,
       log.loghost,
       ('[0:12]={APP,SQL,FTP,MTA,DNS,CFG,MON,PRX,SSH,STO,VCS,VMM,WEB}'::text[])[trunc(random() * 3)] || '-' ||
       TO_CHAR(floor(random() * (100 - 1 + 1)), 'fm000') || '-' ||
       ('[0:3]={DEV,TST,STG,PRD}'::text[])[trunc(random() * 3)] || '-' ||
       TO_CHAR(floor(random() * (100 - 1 + 1)), 'fm000')     AS newloghosttest,
       b.newloghost,
       log.logsourcetype,
       log.logsourcename,
       log.lastlogmessage,
       DATE_PART('day', current_date - log.lastlogmessage) as dayssincelogged
FROM datalake.logsourcesdaily as log
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ('[0:12]={APP,SQL,FTP,MTA,DNS,CFG,MON,PRX,SSH,STO,VCS,VMM,WEB}'::text[])[trunc(random() * 3)] ||
                                    '-' || TO_CHAR(floor(random() * (100 - 1 + 1)), 'fm000') || '-' ||
                                    ('[0:3]={DEV,TST,STG,PRD}'::text[])[trunc(random() * 3)] || '-' ||
                                    TO_CHAR(floor(random() * (100 - 1 + 1)), 'fm000') AS newloghost) b
WHERE log.rundate = (current_date - interval '1 day')
  and log.mpeprocessingmode != 'Disabled'
  AND log.lastlogmessage < (current_date - interval '7 day')
  and log.lastlogmessage != '1900-1-1 00:00'
ORDER BY dayssincelogged desc, log.loghost asc, log.logsourcename asc, log.logsourcename asc;
```

This was my latest attempt. Using the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` tho uses the same single generated value for each row. Where I want to use a newly generated value for each row but for each row reuse the generated value.

Comment: So from what I have read, it appears it is being optimized so it isn't redoing the random each time. I tried to do a WITH instead before the select and I get the same results.

Comment: This question is experiencing a similar optimization problem with random(): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299774/strange-selection-pushdown-in-postgres-13